# HTML output element default value in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, forms, firefox

```html
<form oninput="result.value=parseInt(a.value)+parseInt(b.value)">
  <input type="range" name="b" value="50" /> +
  <input type="number" name="a" value="10" /> =
  <output name="result">60</output>
  <br>
  <button type="reset">Reset</button>
</form>
```

Change the `input` values and then press the reset button. In Firefox, the form reset sets the `output` value to an empty string rather than its default value. It seems that Firefox doesn't understand `HTMLOutputElement.defaultValue`:

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('output').defaultValue);
```

```html
<output id="output">60</output>
```

Is it a bug?

Comment: I think you're better off not using the reset button functionality here. I tried it and confirmed that the output tag isnt reset to 60, perhaps this is because the output doesnt actually contain a default value and is set dynamically? instead use onclick="// lookup both elements and clear their values"

Comment: Found three relevant bugs from mozilla: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1422260 ;  https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1537689 ; https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1419316